# Arrange Tabs Header Position

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

My requirement is to have a tab header position inline with other title. Example like image bellow

[image]

How should I do to implement like this. This my demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aunsjr-jgzut3)

**HTML**

```
<div class="card">
<ngb-tabset>
  <ngb-tab title="One">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>These tabs are 1</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
  <ngb-tab title="Two">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <p>These tabs are 2</p>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the css property `display`. It will help you.

Comment: Well in that case you need some negative magin like make a heading and adjust it by maring in negative values to adjust taht and align right to tabs, its not the perfect solution but a hack

Comment: Thank you for comment... Could you give me an answer.. for more clear

Comment: Is this your requiremnet ? link: https://jpav8z.run.stackblitz.io

Comment: @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier yes.., this my requiment link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, we want to have the same result as it is in the picture.

1. I would change the HTML structure by inserting `tab-content` before `nav-pills`. It makes more sense.
2. Add a correct CSS styles to `ngb-tabset`

CSS styles for `ngb-tabset`

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css flex and give `align-items: flex-end` to get the tabs aligned to right.

Please refer the link below for demo:

https://jpav8z.run.stackblitz.io/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cannot open your link